# Dynamic CSS - move image

Tags: php, css

This CSS bit should move my image a little to left from the right margin but it doesn't. The image is at the left margin now.

```
<?php

$var=60;
?>

<style type="text/css">
p.first {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  right: <?php echo $var; ?>px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

</style>

<p class="first"><img src="images.jpg" /></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using the position attribute in this case.  Try using margin/padding to "move my image a little to left from the right margin"

```
<style type="text/css">
    p.first {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-left: <?php echo $var; ?>px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a float rather than fixed positioning.  You could do something like:

```
float: right;
margin-right: <?php echo $var; ?>px;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for the creating points on a screen question I answered, right?

Instead of p.first, do img.first and just get rid of the p tags.

Might also want to work in top and left rather than bottom and right, so that you have an x y coordinate system with the origin in the top left, but that's just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved. I hate to say this but the problem was that I had saved it earlier as a ".html" and I completely forgot about it.

Thanks for the tips, managed to improve it!